# Hide chart labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) and I can't hide the labels that show in top of every pie chart. Ex:

[image]

And I cannot hide those labels, like AK47, AUG, etc. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way would be to use the legends `generateLabels` function to return an empty string

```
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      generateLabels: function(chart) {
        return "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it does mean you are left with a rather naked looking graph

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/ghppjapj/)

Answer (score 2):

There's a global setting for this.  This will allow you to still have hoverable labels while removing the legend.

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
```

Comment: nice, i didn't try this as for some reason when you specify the display property in the options for the chart it is ignored

Comment: @Quince check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63nm2mgs/) out.  I put two different ways of achieving it using this method in there.

Comment: yeah, i am an idiot who can't spot typo's. this is the best way to achieve the desired result